# custom promise function not giving me any results

Tags: javascript, import, promise, module

I have two js files, scripts.js and utils.js. I imported a custom promise function from utils.js to scripts.js to use but I don't get any results back.

utils.js

```
const waitToLoadImgs = async (imgEls) => {
  const imgElsPromise = await imgEls.map((imgEl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      imgEl.addEventListener("load", () => {
        return resolve("ok");
      });
    });
  });

  const allImgElsLoaded = await Promise.all(imgElsPromise);
  return allImgElsLoaded;
};

export { waitToLoadImgs };
```

scripts.js

```
import {waitToLoadImgs} from "./utils.js";

const imgEls = [...document.querySelectorAll("img")];

const result = await waitToLoadImgs(imgEls);
console.log(result); // <-----Nothing in the console.
```

index.js

```
 <body>
    <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
    <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
    <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
    <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
    <img src="./assets/recycle-bin-remove-icon.svg" />
    <script src="scripts.js" type="module"></script>
 </body>
```

**----------UPDATE----------**

I found out that if I remove `const allImgElsLoaded = await Promise.all(imgElsPromise);` and just return the "imgElsPromise" array. I do finally get an array of promises log out in the console but when I check all promises "PromiseResult", they are all undefined.

utils.js

```
const waitToLoadImgs = async (imgEls) => {
  const imgElsPromise = await imgEls.map((imgEl) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      imgEl.addEventListener("load", () => {
        resolve("ok");
      });
    });
  });

  // Removed the Promise.all
  return imgElsPromise;
};

export { waitToLoadImgs };
```

scripts.js

```
import {waitToLoadImgs} from "./utils.js";

const imgEls = [...document.querySelectorAll("img")];

const result = await waitToLoadImgs(imgEls);
console.log(result); // <-----This time, it does log out an array of promises, but all promises "PromiseResult" are all undefined.
```

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you don't need either `await` in utils.js.

Comment: .map will not return promise ie. will not await. Try to use classic for loop if you want to use await.

Comment: Any chance the images are loading before you're able to attach the event listeners?

Comment: The return value of an event listener is not used. `return resolve` should just be `resolve`.

Comment: Hi Rahul Beniwal, tried using for loop but still get the same result, which is empty array.

Comment: Please see the above update for more detail. I removed the ```Promise.all``` and just return the array of promises, it does log out the array this time but all "PromiseResult" are all undefined.

Comment: I did another test, I found out that everything inside of "imgEl.addEventListener's listener" is not running, console.log won't log out anything inside of the listener.